# MASM: dereference struct pointer twice?

Tags: sockets, winapi, assembly, x86, masm

I've been dabbling in x86 assembly again using MASM, and ran into a small roadblock. Looking to reinvent the wheel out of pure enjoyment.

```
    ASSUME eax:PTR hostent
    mov ebx, [eax].h_addr_list ;this doesn't compile -- but IDE recognizes hostent.h_addr_list
   ;I think I need to dereference the pointer twice, but I have no clue how to do that with MASM.
   ;It sounds silly, yes, but doing the traditional mov eax, [eax] won't solve my compiler error

    mov ecx, [eax].h_name ;this compiles just fine

   ;mov ebx, (hostent PTR [eax]).h_addr_list ;didn't work either.
   ASSUME eax:nothing
```

The problem seems to be that h_addr_list is a char **, while h_name is a char *. The error thrown is:

```
error A2006: undefined symbol : h_addr_list
```

The definition for the hostent structure is:

```
    typedef struct hostent {
  char FAR      *h_name; //note the char FAR *
  char FAR  FAR **h_aliases;
  short         h_addrtype;
  short         h_length;
  char FAR  FAR **h_addr_list; //note the char FAR FAR **
} HOSTENT, *PHOSTENT, FAR *LPHOSTENT;
```

Comment: Still looking for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect you are using *MASM32* and have a line like this:

```
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
```

*windows.inc* contains the HOSTENT structure:

```
hostent STRUCT
  h_name      DWORD      ?
  h_alias     DWORD      ?
  h_addr      WORD       ?
  h_len       WORD       ?
  h_list      DWORD      ?
hostent ENDS
```

Compare that to:

```
typedef struct hostent {
  char FAR      *h_name; //note the char FAR *
  char FAR  FAR **h_aliases;
  short         h_addrtype;
  short         h_length;
  char FAR  FAR **h_addr_list; //note the char FAR FAR **
} HOSTENT, *PHOSTENT, FAR *LPHOSTENT;
```

You'll notice that `h_addr_list` is defined in *windows.inc* as `h_list`. You could either modify *windows.inc* and rename `h_list` or you can modify your code to reference `h_list` instead of `h_addr_list`. I would do the latter as it would keep your code compatible with others using *MASM32*.

It should also be clear that some of the other fields are named a bit differently as well.